# How to update where subquery value is null in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to update a column if another value from a subquery is less than a certain value or null:

```
UPDATE
    Customer
SET
    PriceClassID = 'A'
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        custid,
        SUM(curybaldue) as last_sum
    FROM
        SOShipHeader
    WHERE
        OrdDate > @year_ago
        AND
        Status = 'C'
    GROUP BY
        CustID
    ) a 
    JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustId = a.CustId
    WHERE
        ( last_sum < 3000 OR last_sum IS NULL )
        AND
        PriceClassID IN ('CLUB', 'CLUB-E')
        AND
        Customer.User7 <= @year_ago
        AND
        Customer.User7 > @year_and_month_ago
```

However, when I then check if the `PriceClassID` was changed, I see it was not changed for any row where last_sum was null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run the subquery by itself. Do the returned results match what you're expecting?

Comment: Run a select query and see if it returns any data. ie replace
 `UPDATE   Customer SET PriceClassID = 'A'`
  with `select *`

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting `last_sum` to be null 
(1) because `curybaldue` is null, or 
(2) because there are no rows in `SOShipHeader`, for that `cust-id`?

If it's (1), then your problem is elsewhere:  for a `cust-id` that has *any* non-null values for `curybaldue`, `SUM` would calculate successfully, counting those nulls as zeros.  For a `cust-id` with *all* `curybaldue` are null, `last_sum` would be null, and be selected by your `WHERE`.

If it's (2) -- your code would drop the nulls.  In that case, do the following: 
(A) make the `Customer` table your `FROM` table, and 
(B) use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, to make it an optional link, (because `JOIN` defaults to `INNER JOIN`, dropping all `Customer` rows that do not `JOIN` to `SOShipHeader`):

```
UPDATE
    Customer
SET
    PriceClassID = 'A'
FROM 
    Customer 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
        custid,
        SUM(curybaldue) as last_sum
    FROM
        SOShipHeader
    WHERE
        OrdDate > @year_ago
        AND
        Status = 'C'
    GROUP BY
        CustID
    ) a 
          ON Customer.CustId = a.CustId
    WHERE
        ( last_sum < 3000 OR last_sum IS NULL )
        AND
        PriceClassID IN ('CLUB', 'CLUB-E')
        AND
        Customer.User7 <= @year_ago
        AND
        Customer.User7 > @year_and_month_ago
```